# MouseEvents not working in Java:

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent

MouseEvents not working in Java:
When I drag my mouse nothing happens. This program is supposed to draw while dragging.

Heres the main class:

```
public class GUI {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    simpledrawing xx = new simpledrawing();
    JFrame x = new JFrame();
    x.add(xx,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    x.add(new JLabel("Drag to draw"),BorderLayout.NORTH);
    x.setSize(450,450);
    x.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    x.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Heres the event listener class

```
public class simpledrawing extends JPanel{
private int pc =0;
private Point[] points = new Point[10000];

public simpledrawing(){
     System.out.print("Entered Constructor");
    addMouseMotionListener(
    new MouseMotionAdapter(){
     @Override   
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
            System.out.print("Dragging Mouse");
            if(pc<points.length){
                points[pc] = e.getPoint();
                ++pc;
                repaint();
            }
        }
    });

  }

public void paintComponent( Graphics g )
{
    super.paintComponent( g );
    for( int i=0; i < pc; i++ )
    g.fillOval(points[i].x ,points[i].y , 4, 4);
}
```

Comment: For this exact purpose, use `@Override` annotation for methods you are attempting to override (or implement)

Comment: I tried renaming and also tried adding @Override but somehow it is still not working. I updated my initial post code accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

```
public void MouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
```

Java is case sensitive. The method name should start with a lower case character:

```
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
```

Edit:

Also, when doing custom painting you must override the `getPreferredSize()` method of the panel to return the desired Dimension of your panel, otherwise the size is (0, 0) and there is nothing to paint.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Finally, class names start with an upper case character. Follow Java standards and don't make up your own conventions.

Comment: I tried renaming and also tried adding @Override but somehow it is still not working. I updated my initial post code accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But the line System.out.print("Dragging Mouse"); never gets executed.

Comment: @AhmedRana, `But the line System.out.print("Dragging Mouse"); never gets executed.` And I gave you the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Panel must be focusable:

in simpledrawing constructor call this: setFocusable (true).

On a side note you should name your classes from capital letter. And don't name your objects as x or xx, it makes it more confusing to read.

Comment: -1 a panel does not need to be focusable to receive mouse events. That is for KeyEvents. +1 for following Java naming conventions by starting class names with upper case characters.